# MVC5 Ajax Call using Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update my Razor view content using ajax in ASP.Net MVC 5. But, everytime its loading total page instead of partial request to the controller.

Please help which resources i need to add to my prject to work with ajax in MVC5 speciafically.

Resources Attched to my project to use Ajax:
**jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js**

View Design:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RoomsAvail", "Bookings", new AjaxOptions
                                                     {
                                                     HttpMethod = "GET",
                                                     UpdateTargetId ="RoomsAvailData",
                                                     }))
{
 <div class="col-sm-4 paddingzero margintopclass">
  <button type="submit" value="Search">
   <img src="~/Content/images/search.png" style="cursor:pointer" alt="Search"  />
  </button>
 </div>
 }
```

Booking Controller Action method

```
    public ActionResult RoomsAvail(FormCollection inputParams)
    {

        minRatesInventory="Some Model Data from DB";

        if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("", minRatesInventory);
        }

        return View(minRatesInventory);
    }
```

In the above code snippet, Request.IsAjaxRequest() is always returning false.

### EDIT

 
***I have added jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js before jQuery. It makes problem to call ajax. I have updated this and its working fine.***

Comment: Has jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js been included successfully? Check for script errors in browser console.

Comment: Thanks Valsmas for your quick help on this